# How to solve this integral equation from Lambert Beer's Law?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\begin{align*}
> \int_0^x \frac{dI(x)}{I(x)} dx =- \int_0^x \mu dx\\
> \log I(x) - \log I(0) = -\mu x.
> \end{align*} $$

Why is there a $\log$ function after integration? I am kind of poor at calculus, and derivation is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't add formulae a images.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the variable of integration should be a dummy variable, such as $t$, rather then $x$, as the limits of integration must be constant with respect to the variable of integration. We can evaluate the given integral by substituting $u = I(t)$. Then $du = dI(t)dt$, the new limits of integration are $I(0)$, $I(x)$ and

$$\int_0^x \frac{dI(t)}{I(t)} dt = \int_{I(0)}^{I(x)} \frac{1}{u}du = \left.\log u\right.\vert{_{I(0)}^{I(x)}} = \log I(x) - \log I(0).$$